# Why do words like mean (in the context of '__ means ___') require an s?

Tags: reason-why

I am trying to help a friend of mine from Thailand with his English, and before I correct his usage of 'mean' I'd like to be able to explain the why and wherefore of what I am telling him.  He often sends me messages that say things like "That mean..." and I can't for the life of me determine why that word requires an s in that context.

Comment: Are you speaking here about the third person singular, present tense of the verb *to mean*? That's no exception. Almost every regular verb in English forms the third person in that way.

Comment: Those who have average means are clustered around the mean.

Answer (score 1):

That means -  it's the 3rd (third) person singular so you need to add an s since 'mean' is a verb here.

Comment: How about *It's all those little things that mean I love you*?

Comment: @deadrat: different "that". the subject is "those little things".

Comment: @ColinFine Now, let's not always see the same hands.